# Page shows internal server error after page refresh (using websocket-rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

When I refresh the page where a websocket is open I get a 'Internal server error' on the refreshed page 
I couldn't find any solutions to this problem..I am using rails 4.1.8, websocket-rails gem ,thin server.

this is my rails log...

```
Unexpected error while processing request: deadlock; recursive locking
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:16:in `lock'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:16:in `call'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/faye-websocket-0.8.0/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:40:in `process'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/faye-websocket-0.8.0/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:44:in `receive_data'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

this is my client side code

```
     <script>

     var dispatcher_stock_table = new WebSocketRails($('.table').data('uri'), true);

     dispatcher_stock_table.on_open = function() {
     console.log('Connection has been established:');}

     dispatcher_stock_table.on_close = function(closed) {
     console.log('Connection has been closed:'+closed);}

      var getvalues = function(value){  

             var valuenum = value.split('_')[1];
             var data = {identity: valuenum,value: document.getElementById(value).value};

              console.log(data);

             var success = function(response) {
              console.log("Wow it worked: "+response.message);
              dispatcher_stock_table.unbind('stock_ajax_handler');
              }

             var failure = function(response) {
               console.log("That just totally failed: "+response.message);
              }

             dispatcher_stock_table.trigger('stock_ajax_handler', data, success, failure); 

             function gettable(gettable_and_flashnotice) {
                  console.log(gettable_and_flashnotice.sent_data.notice);
                  dispatcher_stock_table.on_close("closed");
                }
             dispatcher_stock_table.bind('stock_ajax_handler', gettable);
            // var channel = dispatcher.subscribe('<%=current_user.id%>');
            // channel.trigger('notification_update',sent,success,failure);
            // channel.bind('notification_update', function(data) {
            // console.log('channel event received: ' + data);});
            // channel.unbind('notification_update');
};
    <script/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using rails 4.1.8 but still it looks like you have to add this below line to your development.rb file

config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock

Add this to development.rb file ...it solved my problem,reference(http://richardyuwono.org/post/85523208658/heroku-websocket-rails-rails-4) and guys at websocket-rails irc channel(@moa) helped me out